# GCM How to see particular token so i can send to that device only

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

From the demo GCM app, in console i can send push to all devices. But how to send to a particular device? How can i check tokens that are registered to this gcm api?

Comment: While submitting token to your server add your name so you can recognize and able to send noti to target user

Answer (score 0):

By looking up the userID in the database that you are maintaining on your server, match registration IDs with users. It is possible with parse. If you want to send to a specific user, create an additional field in your parse installation and save the userID on this field. You can send to the specific user by filtering with userID and setting the query to get that specific user in the code for sending push.

You can save a userID in `ParseInstallation` and then target this:

Receiver:

```
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
installation.put("user_id", "1234567890");
installation.saveInBackground();
```

Sender:

```
ParseQuery query = ParseInstallation.getQuery(); 
query.whereEqualTo("user_id", "1234567890");    
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setQuery(query);
push.sendPushInBackground();
```